# Dart + Flutter new object creation

Tags: flutter, dart

In dart I can create an object and call a method in two ways:

First one:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
a.methodA();
```

Second one:

```
new classA().methodA();
```

Does it have any negative effect to keep doing this? Let's say I want to call 4-5 methods from ClassA in another class, would it have any negative effects, f.x. on performance by using the second way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's still the exact same object creation process, it's just a simple constructor call. The only difference is that in one case you're giving the result a name (`a`), in the other you're not.

It's not like you're saving memory by not saving the object to a variable. In either case, a reference to your new `ClassA` object needs to exist *somewhere*, (whether explicitly named or not), otherwise how would `methodA` know which object to operate on?

However, there is a difference between:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA()
a.methodA()
a.methodB()
a.methodC()
a.methodD()
a.methodE()
```

versus

```
new ClassA().methodA()
new ClassA().methodB()
new ClassA().methodC()
new ClassA().methodD()
new ClassA().methodE()
```

In the first case, you're reusing the same object `a` (from a single constructor call) as a target of all 5 instance method calls. In the latter case, you have 5 distinct objects (from 5 separate constructor calls), each as a target of a single method call. These can obviously have very different semantics.

Comment: It is the difference you showed that I am talking about. When you say very different semantics, do you mean that it is bad to do the second one, i.e. new ClassA().methodA()?

Comment: @iaminpainpleasehelp1 It's just a completely different situation. Suppose the class in question was `Counter`, whose objects start with a `count` of `0`, and whose `increment()` method increases the count by 1 and returns the new value. `new Counter.increment(); new Counter.increment()` creates two short-lived counters, each incremented once. Both expressions evaluate to `1` (the initial value of 0, + 1 because of the increment). Whereas `Counter c = new Counter;  c.increment(); c.increment()`  makes the expressions return `1` and `2` (an initial count of 0, +1 twice).

Comment: @iaminpainpleasehelp1 Neither is "better", they just mean totally different things. In the abstract like this, they're completely incompatible. It's like asking "What's better, using a `for` loop, or using an `if` statement?" They're just totally different. Without a more concrete example of what class you're dealing with, and what its methods do, there's on way to recommend one or the other.